# Changing the value of an element in an Array which is in another Array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to change a value of an array that is in an another array using `React`.

Here is my array:

```
routes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        points: [{id, address, status}, {id, address, status},]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        points: [{id, address, status}, {id, address, status},]
    },
]
```

And how I have set it up. When user clicks on "Accept" then the status of that specific point should change.

```
{routes.map((route, i) => (
    <div>...</div>
    {route.points.map((point, i) => (
        <Button onClick={() => this.onAcceptClicked(route.points)>Accept</Button>
    ))}
))}
```

Here I am trying to change the value but I am missing something or doing everything completely wrong. Status of that specific point should be set to 2.

```
onAcceptClicked = (points) => {
    const myNewArray = Object.assign([...points], {
        [index]: {
            ...deliveryPoints[index],
            status: 2
        }
    });
    //this.setState({ points: myNewArray }); ... not sure how to do this part
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to update the whole routes in the state.

As you already have the index you can skip the finding part

```
{routes.map((route, i) => (
    <div>...</div>
    {route.points.map((point, j) => (
        <Button onClick={() => this.onAcceptClicked(route.points,i,j)>Accept</Button>
    ))}
```

And update the routes in state like below (i is the index of the item in routes array and j is the index of item in points array)

```
onAcceptClicked = (points,i,j) => {
    const myNewArray = [...this.state.routes];
    myNewArray[i].points[j]={...myNewArray[i].points[j],status:2};
    this.setState({ routes: myNewArray }); 
}

))}
```

Comment: This is still mutating the element at `i` which can result in components not updating correctly. Deeptly nested react states should be avoided for that very reason as it is hard to update it correctly. What you needed to do is to create a new object at `i` and in that object replace `points` with a new array with a new object at `points[j]` too that has a different `status`.

Comment: And set that object to state again ? didnt know that it will work. but i totally agree with not using deeply nested objects

Comment: No I mean you need to create the whole structure again down to the level where the update has to be made, not only the top level. This needs to be done to ensure that if a nested element is passed down as a prop it will be recognised as changed. In your answer you replace the top level array with a new array which is correct but in that array you are still mutating the object instead of replacing it.

Comment: My mistake, yes it wont deepclone missed that, Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I dont think I can avoid nested objects here but I will try to avoid them in the future.

Comment: It might not be a problem in most apps as if a parent re-renders it will re-render its children. But if a child makes a shallow comparison of its props and one prop is the nested object it might break.

Comment: Actually when I'm trying with this answer, it seems to change the status of point in both of the route at that index, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you check the index values that are passed (i and j)?

Comment: The index values seem to be correct.. 0 and 0 when clicking the 1st button.

Comment: and the value of the newArray before setting state ?

Comment: I checked the value of `newArray` before and after the change and before it is correct and after change both of the status' are changed in both routes.

Comment: Anything i'm missing here ? https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-raman-t4uh3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I simply dont get it.. I have it exactly the same way and its changing both.. I will let you know once I figure it out, thank you for everything.

Comment: Hmm.. because I was testing, I was using the same ID's for both of the points list's or well they were set from the same list: `points: pointsList` where `pointsList` was something I had created before. And when I created both of them from different `pointsLists's` so to say then it worked fine. So it seems it still had some kind of reference to that list that it was set with. Eh, thank you a lot for sticking around and helping me find the mistake.